# Stealing something for remembrance - is there any single word for the meaning?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Is there any single word for the meaning "Stealing something for remembrance".
Or how well can we tell this.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

The words normally used to mean something you take for remembrance are *memento*, *souvenir*, *remembrance*, or *keepsake*. None of these imply that they are taken by theft. *Google*: [ [define memento](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+memento) ]

The closest term I can think of is *scalping*, which is the taking of a battle trophy to memorialize one’s bravery. That is stealing, you could say. But you could really only use it correctly if what you are taking is a scalp. *Wikipedia*: “[Scalping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalping)”

Consequently, the simplest phrase might be “**steal a souvenir**”.

Answer (score -3):

Coin it if you will,
 **mementoklept** (neologism)
     *n* one who steals for keepsake
     *v* stealing for keepsakes; *past tense*, mementoklepted

whence,
*mementoklepty*, *mementokleptic*, *mementokleptical*, *mementokleptically*, *mementoklepticality*,   *mementokleptomania*

**[biblioklept, biblioclept](http://wordinfo.info/unit/2525/ip:1/il:K)**
     1. A book thief or someone who steals books.
     2. Besides the direct biblioklept there is the indirect thief who borrows and never returns books to their proper owners (including a library).

Though the *clept* root also exists, I would prefer not to suggest its use, to avoid confusion with *cleft*, which both spells and sounds very similar.

I have not tried to resolve the fact that the roots are from *L* and *Gk*, probably making this an invalid word formation, unlike *biblioklept*.

Comment: While interesting, this still isn't a word...